# How to properly spawn postgresql server via runit

Tags: postgresql, runit

I'm trying to get my head around Voidlinux and runit in particular. Void had postgresql v9 in its repos, I needed something newer, so I compiled v12 from source. It works ok, but now I'm struggling with creating a runit service for it, I've read some manuals, googled a bit and here's what I came up with:

```bsh
# /etc/sv/postgresql/run
#!/bin/sh
exec chpst -u postgres /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l /var/lib/postgresql/logfile start 2>&1
# I've also tried postmaster command, which doesn't work even as standalone, whereas I'm able to launch the server by hand with the command above
```

I've also tried creating an empty directory in `/run/runit/supervise.postgresql` and linking it to `/etc/sv/postgresql` (as well as without it)

After I reboot (or try to manually start the service), I'm getting output:

```
waiting for server to start.... done
server started
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Then the last 4 lines are repeated in an endless loop with no result.
Contents of `/var/lib/postgresql/logfile`:

```
2019-05-10 08:11:15.859 CEST [1138] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2019-05-10 08:11:15.859 CEST [1138] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 760) running in data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"?
2019-05-10 08:11:16.964 CEST [1211] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2019-05-10 08:11:16.964 CEST [1211] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 760) running in data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"?
2019-05-10 08:11:18.070 CEST [1215] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2019-05-10 08:11:18.070 CEST [1215] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 760) running in data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So I did eventually solve the problem, here's the answer for anyone who'd face the same problem. The mistake was actually quite dumb but I got to notice it only after I got to know how logging works in void, somehow only the syslog (but not the postgres log) did show the error that read `SSL is not supported in this build`, so I started digging that way and eventually came up to realize that `-l` flag in the service execution command forces SSL usage, which I didn't need. So the final run file with which I got it all working is:

```
# /etc/sv/postgresql/run:
#!/bin/sh
exec chpst -u postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D '/var/lib/postgresql/data' 2>&1
```

Also, logging for the service is enabled by creating a folder `/etc/sv/postgresql/log` and creating a file in it (`/etc/sv/postgresql/log/run`) with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec logger -p daemon.info -t postgres
```

Also install a syslog daemon to actually get logs stored (for ex. socklog-void)

Comment: It's all too often we think our answers haven't made a difference to anyone else, but today yours has. Thanks for saving me a few hours of debugging time :)